# How can I inform Apple what I dislike in their app and how it can be visible for others?

Tags: apple-music

I do not like some thing in Apple Music and I would like to tell them about this. How can I share this to other people and in same time inform Apple about this?

Comment: What is your definition of being visible to others? You should probably buy a full page advertisement in the New York Times or get Taylor Swift to blog about it if you intend to reach the VP or higher level at Apple. What's the end goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could submit an issue to "[Apple Bug Reporter](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/)"

Even though it's called "Bug Reporter" you can also use it to submit enhancements, suggestions, feature requests, UI/usability issues, etc.

To sign in you need an Apple ID which you probably have anyway.

In a way you also "share this to other people" in this way, because if other people submit similar issues to Bug Reporter it can be linked to your issue, so that they know someone else reported something similar already.

Comment: Thank you, that is the answer I was looking for :-) accepted answer is yours. I do not know why the others voted me down :-) very thanks...

Answer (score 3):

How about their associated [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/applemusic) and [Twitter](https://twitter.com/AppleMusic) accounts?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: That's a a rhetorical question, not a *new* one.

Comment: +1 This is clearly a new avenue in addition to the tried and true apple.com/feedback and bug reporting channels.

Answer (score 2):

Apple Music does not yet have a "[feedback page](https://www.apple.com/feedback/)" but you could try to
use the iPhone or iPad feedback or iTunes feedback pages since Music is integrated into the whole ecosystem.  Each of the pages says that they read all the feedback. Go to the main feedback page and choose the product that you are primarily using Music with and submit your feedback there.